# How to show custom metadata in DSpace's summary view (Mirage)?

Tags: dspace

I tried to use the advice as described by this link:
[How to show custom metadata in DSpace's summary view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074688/how-to-show-custom-metadata-in-dspaces-summary-view?newreg=2484c0ac60b6435ebe7eebcc6eb3e51b)

But, But I have not received any changes, including after a reboot the Tomcat. Can anyone give advice on what I'm doing wrong?

/dspace/webapps/xmlui/themes/Mirage/lib/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl

xmlui.dri2xhtml.METS-1.0.item-issn:

```
                    <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::dim:field[@element='identifier' and @qualifier='issn']) != 0">
                      <br/>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:for-each>
              </span>
          </div>
          <xsl:call-template name="itemSummaryView-DIM-fields">
            <xsl:with-param name="clause" select="($clause + 1)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="phase" select="$otherPhase"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>

      <!-- identifier.uri row -->
      <xsl:when test="$clause = 4 and (dim:field[@element='identifier' and @qualifier='uri' and descendant::text()])">
                <div class="simple-item-view-other">
                <span class="bold"><i18n:text>xmlui.dri2xhtml.METS-1.0.item-uri</i18n:text>:</span>
                <span>
                    <xsl:for-each select="dim:field[@element='identifier' and @qualifier='uri']">
                        <a>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="./node()"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="./node()"/>
                        </a>
                        <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::dim:field[@element='identifier' and @qualifier='uri']) != 0">
                            <br/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </span>
            </div>
          <xsl:call-template name="itemSummaryView-DIM-fields">
            <xsl:with-param name="clause" select="($clause + 1)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="phase" select="$otherPhase"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
```

Comment: If you restarted tomcat, your changes should be visible.  Did you run "mvn package" and "ant update"?  After confirming that the file was deployed properly, you can try clearing the cocoon cache from the Control Panel.

Comment: You're only showing us half the relevant bits - so you are trying to add the ISSN to the summary view? Can you show us the start of that row, ie the corresponding `<xsl:when ...>` tag? You do need to increment the row number in the test for each row such that they are sequential.